# Cordova Plugin FCM reset notifications when enter app via homescreen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

Guys I'm having a problem, all notifications work great, I can receive push with the callback javascript even background when I enter the app and foreground, but how can i reset or clean my app's notification bar when the user access app via home screen? Is there any way to achieve this? I'm using cordova with ionic and the https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm does not seem to achieve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by installing phonegap-plugin-push, this plugin doesn't support this kind of thing as reseting notifications/badges